# the best way to check duration in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

in my mysql table, there are column startYear,startMonth,endYear,endMonth which are all integer (int). there I stored the starting year and month, and ending year and month for something.. for example I want to store the duration of my car instalment, so startYear would have 2012, startMonth would have 8, endYear would have 2019, endMonth would have 7

ok so since now the actual current month is 9 (september) and year 2013, what is the best way/query for me to check whether the current month and year is within the startYear,startMonth and endYear,endMonth?

Comment: You might want to think about using a column with DATE datatype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) will check to see if the values are greater than or equal to the first number, and less than or equal to the second number.

```
IF (MONTH(CURDATE()) BETWEEN startMonth and endMonth) AND (YEAR(CURDATE()) BETWEEN startYear and endYear))
```

Comment: This isn't correct. What if the start is Oct, 2011 and end is Feb, 2013. Jan, 2012 should be between them, but the above formula will say it isn't.

Comment: yup it's not correct, but it got me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CURDATE() BETWEEN CONCAT_WS('-', startYear, startMonth, '01')
                  AND CONCAT_WS('-', endYear, endMonth, '31');
```